# Whats wrong with my SQL Query? (not getting desired o/p)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want my query to return number of users registered in a particular day between current date and 7 days before. Instead of days, in date-time format it shows it in integer format. Example, for date 20/12/2012 its showing as 0, 21/12/2012 as 1 and so on

My Query:

```
select date(update_timestamp) between date_sub(sysdate(), interval 7 day) and sysdate()  as date, count(*) users 
from registered 
group by date(update_timestamp)
```

Desired Output

```
DATE       | USERS
20/12/2012 | 5
21/12/2012 | 6
```

Output i'm getting

```
DATE  | USERS
    0 | 5
    1 | 6
```

What is wrong with my sql query? Also, i need to know the alternate way of fetching last 7 days data

Comment: can u show also your table how it looks like ?

Comment: @peter registered(update_timestamp,users,passwrd,domain,dept_location) anyway its reolved :) i'm getting the desired o/p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have put the condition in the `select` statement, so it will be evaluated and returned, instead of limiting the result. Put the condition in the `where` statement:

```
select date(update_timestamp) as date, count(*) users
from registered
where date(update_timestamp) between date_sub(sysdate(), interval 7 day) and sysdate()
group by date(update_timestamp)
```

---

To get all the dates in the interval even if there are no users, you need to join in another source of data:

```
select date_sub(sysdate(), interval d.offset day) date, count(r.update_timestamp) users
from registered r
inner join (
  select 0 as offset union all
  select 1 union all
  select 2 union all
  select 3 union all
  select 4 union all
  select 5 union all
  select 6 union all
  select 7
) d on date(r.update_timestamp) = date_sub(sysdate(), interval d.offset day)
group by date_sub(sysdate(), interval d.offset day)
```

Comment: query working good. However i want each days record of total number of users registered.Like on 20/10/2012--->5 21/10/2012--->6 etc

Comment: @Vinayak: That's what I thought that it did. What do you get?

Comment: Hello, i also want to know how i can display rows(date) where count(number of users) is zero? using the same query!

Comment: @Vinayak: For that you need to join in another source of data. I added an example above.

Comment: The query is working good. i modified it with _date_sub_ method like 
`inner join (select date(date_sub(sysdate(), interval 7 days as offset union all....*(for 7 days)) d` showing me no error, however it is not displaying any values as well. I should've got 12 rows

Comment: @Vinayak: I made a correction to the query. It should have an `on` instead of `where`.

Comment: afraid :s still displaying _0 row(s) returned_

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a `WHERE` clause:

```
select date(update_timestamp) Date, count(*) users 
from registered 
where date(update_timestamp) between date_sub(sysdate(), interval 7 day) and sysdate()
group by date(update_timestamp)
```

Comment: the query is working good, however, im using it in a chart control in my .net application and i want x axis to contain all the date from last 7 days and y axis as the sum of registered users. So i need both users and date as the result

Comment: i want each days record of total numbers of users registered on that particular day...

Comment: @Vinayak please edit your original post with some sample data and then the desired result.

Comment: Hello, i also want to know how i can display rows(date) where count(number of users) is zero? using the same query!

Answer (score 1):

try this query ::

where clause is the filtering part, For the date type logic you should use your current day - 7 days logic in that part of the query.

```
select date(update_timestamp) ,count(*) users 
from registered 
where date(update_timestamp) 
between 
date_sub(sysdate(), interval 7 day) and sysdate()  
group by date(update_timestamp)
```

Comment: You should explain what was wrong and what you have changed, not just post a working solution. How will they learn?

Comment: @AjithSasidharan what im looking for is that, i want each days record of number of users registered on that particular day.

Comment: sorry forgot the date part in select query.

Comment: Hello, i also want to know how i can display rows(date) where count(number of users) is zero? using the same query!